Powershell script: I wanted to export duplicate IPs from a text file
I have a text file with IP addresses and time stamp. I wanted to export the duplicate IPs to a text file if their time stamp difference between the duplicates is greater than 10 mins.
For example: Something like this
1.1.1.1 2024-03-15T13:01:13
2.2.2.2 2024-03-15T17:02:11
1.1.1.1 2024-03-15T13:15:25

with this in text file, I would like to get in the export that IP (1.1.1.1) since the time stamp difference is more than 10 mins.
I tried the following but the output is empty.
Any assistance/guidance where I made a mistake
`# Function to extract IP addresses and their timestamps from a text file
function Get-IPsWithTimestamps {
    param (
        [string]$FilePath
    )

    # Read the content of the file
    $fileContent = Get-Content -Path $FilePath -Raw

    # Use regex to find IP addresses and timestamps in yy-MM-DD HH-MM-SS format
    $matches = [regex]::Matches($fileContent, "(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)\s+(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})")

    # Create a hashtable to store IP addresses and their timestamps
    $ipTimestamps = @{}

    # Iterate through matches and update timestamps for each IP
    foreach ($match in $matches) {
        $ip = $match.Groups[1].Value
        $timestamp = [datetime]::ParseExact($match.Groups[2].Value, "yy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss", $null)
        $ipTimestamps[$ip] += , $timestamp
    }

    return $ipTimestamps
}

**# Function to filter duplicate IPs with occurrence time difference greater than 10 minutes**
function Get-DuplicateIPsWithTimeDifference {
    param (
        [hashtable]$IPsWithTimestamps
    )

    $duplicateIPsWithTimeDifference = @()

    # Iterate through hashtable and filter duplicate IP addresses
    foreach ($ip in $IPsWithTimestamps.Keys) {
        $timestamps = $IPsWithTimestamps[$ip]
        if ($timestamps.Count -ge 2) {
            $firstTimestamp = $timestamps[0]
            $lastTimestamp = $timestamps[-1]
            $timeDifference = $lastTimestamp - $firstTimestamp
            if ($timeDifference.TotalMinutes -gt 10) {
                $duplicateIPsWithTimeDifference += $ip
            }
        }
    }

    return $duplicateIPsWithTimeDifference
}

# Example usage
$filePath = "C:\path\to\your\textfile.txt"
$ipTimestamps = Get-IPsWithTimestamps -FilePath $filePath
$duplicateIPsWithTimeDifference = Get-DuplicateIPsWithTimeDifference -IPsWithTimestamps $ipTimestamps

# Export unique duplicate IP addresses with time difference greater than 5 minutes to a text file
$duplicateIPsWithTimeDifference | Out-File -FilePath "C:\path\to\output\duplicate_ips_with_time_difference.txt"`




Could you provide a sample of your file?

Hi Santiago. Something like this
1.1.1.1 2024-03-15T13:01:13
2.2.2.2 204-3-15T17:02:11
1.1.1.1 2024-03-15T13:15:25
with this in text file, I would like to get in the export that IP (1.1.1.1) since the time stamp difference is more than 10 mins

the reason for the file being empty is simply because the regex pattern you have is incorrect, example '1.1.1.1 2024-03-15T13:01:13' -match '(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)\s+(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})' outputs false. Can you please confirm the sample output added to your question is exactly what you have in your file? and if so, where is this regex pattern coming from?

there is also one timestamp having 204-3-15T17:02:11 instead of 2024-3-15T17:02:11 was this a typo or is that really from your file?

It was a typo. I edited the file now. My knowledge on regex is so limited. From my research on some tutorials, I thought this was the right regex for the file format I have.

if the file is always an ip address followed by a space followed by a timestamp then a new line an repeat then its just simpler to use -split

Your code looks fine it's just that the regex pattern is incorrect, in particular the DateTime capturing group:
(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2})

It should be:
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})

And, if you wanted to simplify the whole pattern, you could probably use:
((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\s+(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2})

See https://regex101.com/r/7jJy8X/1 for details.
However, if the file consists of always an IP address followed by a space followed by a timestamp then a new line an repeat, its just simpler to use -split:
$ip, $timestamp = '1.1.1.1 2024-03-15T13:01:13' -split '\s+'
$ip        # 1.1.1.1
$timestamp # 2024-03-15T13:01:13

As for how you can approach your code, I think you can make it much simpler by using Group-Object:
# sample data, actually comes from `Get-Content -Raw`
$fileContent = @'
1.1.1.1 2024-03-15T13:01:13
2.2.2.2 2024-03-15T17:02:11
1.1.1.1 2024-03-15T13:15:25
'@

# group the objects by IP and filter out all groups with a single object
$pattern = '((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\s+(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2})'
$groups = [regex]::Matches($fileContent, $pattern) | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        IpAddress = $_.Groups[1].Value
        Timestamp = $_.Groups[2].Value -as [datetime]
    }
} | Group-Object IpAddress | Where-Object Count -GT 1

# for each group, first sort the timestamps (if the file is actually sorted then this step could be removed)
# then get a timespan of the last and first items in the group and check if
# the time difference is greater than 10 minutes, if so, output the ip address
$limitspan = [timespan]::FromMinutes(10)
$groups | ForEach-Object {
    $sorted = $_.Group.Timestamp | Sort-Object

    # if the file is sorted, here you can use:
    # `$_.Group[-1].Timestamp - $_.Group[0].TimeStamp -gt $limitspan`
    if ($sorted[-1] - $sorted[0] -gt $limitspan) {
        $_.Name
    }
} | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\path\to\output\duplicate_ips_with_time_difference.txt'

